# MoveIt! for multiple robots

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've spawned 2 similar robots(with their controllers) with distinct namespaces (robot1,robot2) in Gazebo according to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434). I intend to run two separate moveit instances to control them.

For now I've been trying to control one of them while the other is present in simulation.
The problem that I face is that gazebo publishes joint states as `robot1/joint_states` and `robot2/joint_states` but I get an error saying joint_states not found.
So I remapped  `robot1/joint_states` to `/joint_states` and all works fine but this would be a problem when i try to control the second robot.
The rqt_graph after remap is attached :  [image: C:\fakepath\rosgraph2.png]

how can I make moveit subscribe to `robot1/joint_states` ?
or is there any other way to do this ?

PS : I do not want to run both robots using the same moveit node

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307197/moveit!-for-multiple-robots/) by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) on 2018-10-30**:
Will it work if i include moveit also in 'robot1' namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it !

Adding a `<group ns="robot1">` tag inside my moveit launch file brought the whole moveit into my "robot1" namespace.
Here is the new rqt_graph :[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) with karma: 71 on 2018-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2019-12-05**:
Hi did u used single urdf file for both the robots??